# Able to transform observation to 0 but had issue with their total

Tags: sas

I have a raw data set looks like this:
[enter link description here](https://rit0-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/jc3992_rit_edu/EXVrmjuCExtArCWAfxH6yscBHw75BwRwVK0Awa-XD2GsLg?e=BhaiCn)

And I tried to transform the observations having a "T" to 0,
and then read in the data set and print out. Just this.

However, with my code, simply by looking at the first observation in line 5, it is apparently something is off. 
For instance, the first observation for "Nov" should not be 0.

I could not figure out what had gone wrong and I wonder is anyone would like to give me some advice on what I can do for the next? Thank you very much! Highly appreciated.

My code is as below:

```
    INFILE "&DIRLSB.Pr1Snowfall1.csv" DSD FIRSTOBS=5;
  DROP i;
  INPUT Season $@;
  INPUT Year 1-4  Season 1-7 Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Total;
  ARRAY Months (*) Sep -- May;
  DO i = 1 TO dim(Months);
  IF Months(i)=. Then Months(i)=0;
  END;
  RUN;
```

Comment: Why do you have the first INPUT statement?

Comment: Put value to the "Season" variable from the first starting column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a missing T; statement somewhere that is reading T(race) as missing T.  ".T does not equal ."

I would use coalesce function.  There is really no need to change missing T to 0 is there?

```
missing t;
data snow;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   input Season:$7. Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Total;  
   array mth[*] Sep--May;
   do i = 1 to dim(mth);
      mth[i] = coalesce(mth[i],0);
      end;
   t = sum(of mth[*]);
   drop i;
   cards;
Season Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Total 
1884-85 0 T 1 27.1 22.2 17 3.5 19.5 T 90.3 
1885-86 0 1.7 8.2 8.4 16.9 16 6.5 7 0 64.7 
1886-87 0 T 22.2 12.5 12 18.4 6.3 1.2 0 72.6 
1893-94 0 0.5 6.1 27.6 20 29.5 5.4 13.3 0 102.4 
1894-95 0 T 11.1 22.1 26.5 23.6 9.5 0.6 0 93.4 
1895-96 0 1.5 5.9 8.7 22.5 39.1 45.1 1 0 123.8 
1896-97 0 T 5.5 13.9 20.1 13.7 8.1 5.2 0 66.5 
1897-98 0 0 10.1 18.4 32.1 26.8 1.2 2.4 0 91 
1898-99 0 T 10.6 27 16.6 16.3 21.2 4.3 T 96 
1899-00 T T 1.3 21.5 24.7 28.5 54 1.3 0 131.3 
1906-07 0 5 5.7 18.7 11.7 15.7 3.1 2.5 1.3 63.7 
1907-08 0 0 2.2 11.6 16.5 19.8 7.9 6.3 3 67.3 
1908-09 0 0.5 4.6 10 22.5 6.1 9.7 9.8 3.3 66.5 
1909-10 0 T 1.7 14.6 22 42.7 3.4 0.5 0 84.9 
1910-11 0 2.2 15.7 29.8 9.5 30 13.5 4.7 2 107.4 
1911-12 0 0 6.5 7.5 21.5 10.8 8.8 6.9 T 62 
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: I have looked up the function "coalesce" but I did not quite understand why we needed it here? mth[i] = coalesce(mth[i],0); Was this your attempt to ask SAS to present 0 for all the missing values in mth[i]? Then what was t doing here? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, Coalesce replaces missing with 0 in this instance.

Comment: @Jen-LiChen I thought you were trying to change the missing snowfall values to 0, COALSECE.  T=SUM... was just a check for TOTAL.  Do you have what you need now?  If not please show data that you expect.